# I cannot create pdf file from a new Miktex

Tags: hyperref, compiling

I bought a new computer and downloaded MiKTeX and winedt. I cannot get a pdf file from my tex file. I don't know the reason of it. I deleted many things from my tex file, but it didn't work. Would you help me? Thanks in advance.

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "sample"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\user\Desktop\mathematics

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: sample.aux
The style file: Definitions/mdpi.bst
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file sample.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "MR1946560"
(There was 1 error message)


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "sample.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\user\Desktop\mathematics

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(sample.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14> (Definitions/mdpi.cls
Document Class: Definitions/mdpi 15/02/2019 MDPI paper class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\calc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\indentfirst.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/grfext\grfext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lastpage\lastpage.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lineno\lineno.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/float\float.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/setspace\setspace.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/enumitem\enumitem.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\mathpazo.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/titlesec\titlesec.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tabto-ltx\tabto.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\array.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/soul\soul.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/multirow\multirow.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\microtype-pdftex.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.te
x")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-pdf.def
")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.t
ex")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
" ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometr
ic.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code
.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarit
hmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.c
ode.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.
tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations
.code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex"
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.te
x"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.t
ex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.co
de.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.t
ex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex"))
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.te
x") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.te
x")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.
sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.
sty")) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex"

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.
code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex"
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/totcount\totcount.sty")
(Definitions/journalnames.tex)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyphenat\hyphenat.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/atbegshi\atbegshi.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/atveryend\atveryend.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/footmisc\footmisc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.cfg"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/newfloat\newfloat.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/caption\caption3.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\latexsym.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def")
(sample.aux) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\t1ppl.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\mt-ppl.cfg")
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\gettitlestring.sty"))
(sample.out) (sample.out)
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\varphi' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\varphi' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\varphi' on input line 148.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 148.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1ppl.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\omlzplm.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\omszplm.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\omxzplm.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\ot1zplm.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\mt-msa.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/microtype\mt-msb.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ulasy.fd")

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/lasy/b/n' in size <18> not available
(Font)              size <17.28> substituted on input line 148.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/lasy/b/n' in size <13.6799> not available
(Font)              size <14.4> substituted on input line 148.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\t1cmss.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/psnfss\ts1ppl.fd")

AED: lastpage setting LastPage

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 217--217
  \TS1/ppl/m/n/9 ?\T1/ppl/m/n/9 (+20) 2020 by the au-thors. Sub-mit-ted to \T1
/ppl/m/it/9 (+20) Math-e-mat-ics \T1/ppl/m/n/9 (+20) for pos-si-ble open ac-ces
s pub-li-ca-tion

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 217--217
\T1/ppl/m/n/9 (+20) un-der the terms and con-di-tions of the Cre-ative Com-mons
 At-tri-bu-tion (CC BY) li-cense
[1{C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map} <./Definiti
ons/logo-mdpi-eps-converted-to.pdf> <./Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.
pdf>] [2] (sample.aux

Package natbib Warning: Citation(s) may have changed.
(natbib)                Rerun to get citations correct.

)Trying to make PK font fplmr at 600 DPI...
The METFAONT mode is: ljfour
Running miktex-makemf.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
Running miktex-ttf2pk.exe...

Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log


LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 0.7201pt have occurred.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file fplmr): Font fplmr at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 14   Bad Boxes: 2
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I solved the problem with Miktex update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is solved with a MikTeX update.

Comment: @Fran Okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with Miktex update. See https://miktex.org/howto/update-miktex